# Replace the text with regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex, .net-4.0

I have the following strings:

```
  This is my testasdasd  [Test(XYZ="P")] abc sdfsdf
    This is my testasdasd  [Test(ABC="P")] sdfsdf
    This is my testdfsdfsdf  [Test(DEF="P")] sdfsdfs
    This is my testsdfsdfsdf  [Test(GHI="P")] asdfasdasd
```

I want the add ", Hello" text after the ")" inn the above strings. My output should look like this:

```
This is my testasdasd [Test(XYZ="P"), Hello] abc sdfsdf
This is my testasdasd [Test(ABC="P"), Hello] sdfsdf
This is my testdfsdfsdf [Test(DEF="P"), Hello] sdfsdfs
This is my testsdfsdfsdf  [Test(GHI="P"), Hello] asdfasdasd
```

Can you help me making regex for that?

EDIT: I can't do the above just by doing find and replace "]" I have other brackets too in my strings. I need to find [Test(..)] and the output should be [Test(...) , Hello]

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just replace the `]` with `, Hello]`?  A RegEx would be overkill, IMO.

Comment: If the format is always the same, [String.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx) would be worth looking at as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the lookup expression:

```
@"(\[\s*Test\s*\(.*?\)\s*)\]"
```

and this replace expression:

```
"$1,Hello]"
```

Answer (score 0):

replace regex `(?<=\[Test\(\w+?="P"\))\]` with string `, Hello]`

Comment: don't forget to set the comma after the )

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you do not want to use a regex:

```
String newString = yourString.replace( "]", ", Hello]" );
```

This will only work correctly, if there is only one "]" in your string..

Comment: what about if you have a ']' inside a string ?

Comment: inside which string? The one after "Test(XXX=" ?

Answer (score 0):

If the content is going to be static. Trying `string.replace` will do. My view :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function insert(string, word) {
    return string.replace(/\[Test\(.+\)\]/g, function(a, b) {
        return a.replace("]", ", " + word + "]");
    });
}

insert('This is my testasdasd  [Test(XYZ="P")] abc sdfsdf', "Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(\[Test\([^\)]*\))\]
```

replace with

```
$1, Hello]
```

your code can be like this:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"(\[Test\([^\)]*\))\]", "$1, Hello]");
```

or this simle replace:

```
var result = inputString.replace( "]", ", Hello]" );
```